# Minimax without a tree

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, minimax, minmax

Minimax is often illustrated with a tree,but I know that it can be implemented without the tree !However,I can not figure out how to do it without the tree!Can you clarify it for me?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11704019/951890

Comment: I don't know the definition of minimax exactly but I think that it depends on the problem whether you can simplify it. I also think that it often uses recursive calls instead of building the tree explicitly.

Comment: minimax is designed for exploring state space, which **always** can be represented as a directed graph, thus can be also considered as a tree (simply forgetting about collision detection), thus **minimax always works on the tree**, even if you do not explicitly implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimax by definition always works like a tree, no matter how you implement it. How you visualise it is another story.

Usually, Minimax is implemented recursively (which can be best visualised using a tree) or iteratively, which still goes through the nodes of a minimax tree, just with another approach.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the first comment, minimax is formally defined on a tree structure but for many practical applications it's not necessary to formally compute over the entire tree, and even the game tree structure does not need to be known beforehand- if the possible next moves and termination (game over) states are known, the tree can be built as the algorithm runs. For non-reversible games (like tic tac toe) duplicate states at different points of the tree have the same partial subtrees; hence the only structure that needs to be learned is the value of each state, calculated by minimax; these values can be cached as well for reuse during the algorithm.

By the way, one interesting and popular application of this 'non-explicit tree structure' use of minimax is [Generative Adversarial Networks](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2014/file/5ca3e9b122f61f8f06494c97b1afccf3-Paper.pdf):

From the abstract

`..a generative model G that captures the data distribution, and a discriminative model D that estimates the probability that a sample came from the training data rather than G. The training procedure for G is to maximize the probability of D making a mistake. This framework corresponds to a minimax two-player game.`